# Remove event handler if controls unlocked with three.js pointerlock controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model I'm navigating using the threejs pointerlock controls. Clicking on certain sections of the model when the camera is "looking" at them will take you to other parts of the site. This all works well, except for the specific situation where the camera is centered over a section and you escape out of the pointerlock.  Clicking to go back into pointerlock not only traps the mouse, but also calls the event handler and sends the user elsewhere.

The solution is to remove the event handler, but my code to do so isn't working.  This is the code for the for statement that defines the bounding box of the space to clickthrough and adds the listener.

```
for (var p = 0; p < panels.length; p++ ) {
    //console.log(p);
    if (point_x <= panels[p].x_max && point_x >= panels[p].x_min) {
        x_value = "true";
        if (point_y <= panels[p].y_max && point_y >= panels[p].y_min) {
            y_value = "true";
            if (point_z <= panels[p].z_max && point_z >= panels[p].z_min) {
                z_value = "true";
                clickthrough.innerHTML = panels[p].wall.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + panels[p].wall.slice(1) + " Wall, " + "Panel " + panels[p].panel;
                clickthrough.style.display = 'block';
                //console.log(panels[p].wall.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + " Wall, " + "Panel " + panels[p].panel);

                if (controls.isLocked) {
                    console.log ('controls locked');
                    window.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

                    window.location.href = panels[p].url;

                    }, false );
                }
                else {
                    console.log ('controls unlocked');
                    window.removeEventListener( 'click', function () {

                    window.location.href = panels[p].url;

                      });
                    }

                    break;
                  }
                  else {    z_value = "false";
                        clickthrough.style.display = 'none';}}
                  else {    y_value = "false";
                        clickthrough.style.display = 'none';}}
                  else {z_value = "false";
                        clickthrough.style.display = 'none';}
                       }

                 }
```

The particular section that generates or removes the window listener is:

```
    if (controls.isLocked) {
        console.log ('controls locked');
        window.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    
        window.location.href = panels[p].url;
    
          }, false );
        }
        else {
                console.log ('controls unlocked');
                window.removeEventListener( 'click', function () {window.location.href = panels[p].url;});
        }
```

I suspect the issue is that I'm simply not invoking the removeEventListener correctly, but I'm not sure how to do so.  And if I am invoking it correctly, is there a way I can make sure it works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided is adding and removing two different functions:

```
if (controls.isLocked) {
    console.log ('controls locked');
    window.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

        // this function instance
        window.location.href = panels[p].url;

    } );
} else {
    console.log ('controls unlocked');
    window.removeEventListener( 'click', function () {

        // is different from this function instance
        window.location.href = panels[p].url;

    } );
}
```

If you would like to later remove a function that you've added as an event listener you need to save a handle to the original function reference:

```
const originalFunction = function () {

    window.location.href = panels[p].url;

};

if (controls.isLocked) {
    console.log ('controls locked');
    window.addEventListener( 'click', originalFunction );
} else {
    console.log ('controls unlocked');
    window.removeEventListener( 'click', originalFunction );
}
```

Comment: This worked, but for some odd reason in my particular case I had to add an if statement into the handle function.  I suspect that's due to some oddity in the lock code.  Thank you, though -- I would have been bashing my head repeatedly if this had gone unanswered.